# Add a Personal Package Archive (PPA)

Tags: ppa, software-sources

I cann't Add a Personal Package Archive (PPA) to Software Sources

when I write ppa: location. and Click Add Source the buttone don't worke

what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

To add a PPA, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:<PPA_Name>
```

And then do

```
sudo apt-get update
```

To download the package lists from the repositories and "updates" them.